# Vue.JS data property not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been trying to show my modal but for some reason it keeps saying that the property isn't defined even though I have declared it in the `Data()`

I feel like I am missing something critical to my understanding on how this all works ...

The property is defined as `false` on load and should turn to `true` on click of the button.

```
 <template>
  <div class="product-item">
    <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{product.tagline}}</p>
    <img class="product-image" :src="product.image_url">
    <p>PH: {{product.ph}}</p>
    <button class="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show a tip</button>
    <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false"></modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from "@/components/Modal.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Modal
  },
  Data() {
    showModal: false
  },
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {},
  mounted() {}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You data Object should be returned via a function like :

```
data(){
    return{
      showModal: false
        }
   }
```

`data` should be in lowercase .

Answer (score 0):

A component’s data option must be a `function`, so that each instance can maintain an `independent copy of the returned data object`:

`data: function () {
  return {
    ...
  },
 }`

```js
import Modal from "@/components/Modal.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Modal
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      showModal: false
    },
  }
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {},
  mounted() {}
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="product-item">
    <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{product.tagline}}</p>
    <img class="product-image" :src="product.image_url">
    <p>PH: {{product.ph}}</p>
    <button class="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show a tip</button>
    <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false"></modal>
  </div>
</template>
```